# DBDateTimePicker Validation

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, ado

i downloaded a DBDateTimePicker which i am using to edit dates in a table, a start date and completion date. When appending to a table in normal edit boxes i use the following code before the append and post in order to prevent a completion date being set before a start date.

```
if  (DTPAddStartDate.Date) > (DTPAddCompletionDate.Date) then
begin

      raise Exception.Create ('The Completion date of a Job can not be before a Start Date');
      abort;
end;
```

The problem is that i want to be able to achieve the same thing when editing dates via the DBDateTimePickers, if i have similar code on the BeforePost event or something then i will get premature error messages as the user may not have had a chance to edit the other related DBDateTimePicker. I have no idea how i could relate the two fields so that i can validate them together somehow or come up with another solution to the problem, any suggestions?
(Im using an adotable connected to access and the component was downloaded from the following link, http://apollosoft.net/jms/).

Comment: Could you be more specific with the component (from where did you get it) ?

Comment: The `abort` is not executing, but I guess this is not your real code.

Comment: hi, sorry i haven't had a chance to try out your answer yet but the component is from the link that you posted, i will also put it in my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are using the [`TDBDateTimePicker`](http://apollosoft.net/jms/DBDateTimePicker.zip) from [`this page`](http://apollosoft.net/jms/) but hard to say, it's missing in your question at this time.

However you may use the field's [`OnValidate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TField.OnValidate) event which is being fired whenever the value is changed, but it's the stage when the data are going to be written do the database, so it's IMHO the unnecessary wasting of time.

You can validate the values before they tries to update the record, what is in the case of (almost ?)
every DB aware control when you try to exit the control, so you may pretty easily add some validation event, something like `OnCanUpdate` to your date time picker.

Because of missing link to the source where did you get your component I'll assume you are using this [`TDBDateTimePicker`](http://apollosoft.net/jms/DBDateTimePicker.zip). If you add to the `DBDateTimePicker.pas` file the following lines and rebuild your package where is installed, the new `OnCanUpdate` event will appear in the component's Object Inspector. This event if you use it has one important parameter `Allowed`, if you set it to True you will allow the component to update the record, if you set it to False (what is default) no data will be updated in your dataset. So it's the place where you can do the validation and decide you want to update record or not.

```
type
  TDBDateTimePicker = class;
  TOnCanUpdate = procedure(Sender: TDBDateTimePicker; 
    var Allowed: Boolean) of object;
  TDBDateTimePicker = class(TDateTimePicker)
  private
    FOnCanUpdate: TOnCanUpdate;
    procedure CMExit(var Message: TCMExit); message CM_EXIT;
  published
    property OnCanUpdate: TOnCanUpdate read FOnCanUpdate write FOnCanUpdate;
  end;

procedure TDBDateTimePicker.CMExit(var Message: TCMExit);
var
  Allowed: Boolean;
begin      
  if Assigned(FOnCanUpdate) then
  begin
    Allowed := False;
    FOnCanUpdate(Self, Allowed);    
    if not Allowed then
    begin
      SetFocused(True);
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  try
    FDataLink.UpdateRecord;
  except
    SetFocus;
    raise;
  end;
  SetFocused(False);
  inherited;
end;
```

So the code in the `OnCanUpdate` event may looks like this (note you can use this event as common for both of your date time pickers).

```
procedure TForm1.DTPAddStartDateCanUpdate(Sender: TDBDateTimePicker; 
  var Allowed: Boolean);
begin
  if (DTPAddStartDate.Date) > (DTPAddCompletionDate.Date) then
  begin
    // the Allowed parameter is in current code initialized to False
    // when it comes into this event, so the following line has no
    // sense here
    Allowed := False;
    // here you can display the error message or raise exception or just
    // whatever you want, the record won't be modified in any way
    Application.MessageBox('The completion date of a job cannot be before a ' +
      'start date. The record won''t be modified ;-)', 'Date Input Error...',
      MB_YESNO + MB_ICONSTOP + MB_TOPMOST);
  end
  else
    // only setting the Allowed to True will actually allows the record to be
    // updated, so if your validation passes, set the Allowed to True
    Allowed := True;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Caviate:
A shot in the dark here since the component isn't familiar. If you have the components in a form then the objects are member variables of the form. Assuming they are created when the form is initialized (you're using them so they are) simple check an event when they lose focus.

```
//Pseudo Code--I'm sure it is using a standard event model
myForm.DTPAddCompletionDate.OnChange(...)
begin
  //do your check if it is successful something like... 
  if not (DTPAddStartDate.Date > DTPAddCompletionDate.Date) then
    return;
  else
    someSubmitButton.enabled = true;
end;
```

I don't have Delphi in front of me and it has been years so the code probably won't match up perfectly. However, the idea should work. Just check the references.